# About Change Directory Command

Tags: command-line

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.
The `cd..` and `cd.` commands are not working on my terminal.
It gives error as,

```
cd..: command not found
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Did you have a whitespace between `cd` and `..` ?

Answer (score 3):

`cd` is the command and `..` is its argument. Bash is looking for a command `cd..` which doesn't exist.

Put a space between the command and the argument and it works fine:

```
zanna@monster:~/playground/boom$ cd ..
zanna@monster:~/playground$
```

I can't think of a situation when I would need to `cd .` ;)